# Embed Flash video player does not align top left

Tags: html, object, video, embed

Embed flash video player does not align top left, how to fix it?

Image:

[image]

Source:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="1500" height="1414" id="jcplayer" align="TL" salign="TL">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="videoURL=../{$video_file}&autoPlay=false&startPhotoSource={$video_cover}&backgroundColor1=0x333333&backgroundColor2=0x222222">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="salign" value="TL" />
<param name="scale" value="noScale" />
<param name="movie" value="jcvideoplayer/jcplayer.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />    
<embed src="jcvideoplayer/jcplayer.swf" FlashVars="videoURL=../{$video_file}&autoPlay=false&startPhotoSource={$video_cover}&backgroundColor1=0x333333&backgroundColor2=0x222222" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="500" height="414" name="jcvideoplayer/jcplayer" align="top" salign="TL" scale="noScale" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `hieght` and `width` of the video player itself is too large. Try using firebug to find out if there is some extra padding/margin that is getting applied.

Answer (score 0):

The height and weight are not the same in the object and embed code. Fix that to see if it helps.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="500" height="414" id="jcplayer" align="TL" salign="TL">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="videoURL=../{$video_file}&autoPlay=false&startPhotoSource={$video_cover}&backgroundColor1=0x333333&backgroundColor2=0x222222">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="salign" value="TL" />
<param name="scale" value="noScale" />
<param name="movie" value="jcvideoplayer/jcplayer.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />    
<embed src="jcvideoplayer/jcplayer.swf" FlashVars="videoURL=../{$video_file}&autoPlay=false&startPhotoSource={$video_cover}&backgroundColor1=0x333333&backgroundColor2=0x222222" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="500" height="414" name="jcvideoplayer/jcplayer" align="top" salign="TL" scale="noScale" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this issue with using javascript creating video-element, and some changing base jcvideoplayer js files.

```
function run_video(div_id, videoURL, fotoURL) {

    if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
        alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
    } else {
        playerHTML = AC_FL_RunContent(
            'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
            'width', '550',
            'height', '455',
            'src', 'jcplayer',
            'quality', 'high',
            'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
            'align', 'middle',
            'play', 'true',
            'loop', 'true',
            'scale', 'noScale',
            'wmode', 'window',
            'devicefont', 'false',
            'id', 'jcplayer',
            'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
            'name', 'jcplayer',
            'menu', 'true',
            'allowFullScreen', 'true',
            'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
            'FlashVars','videoURL='+videoURL+'&autoPlay=false&startPhotoSource='+fotoURL+'&backgroundColor1=0x333333&backgroundColor2=0x222222',
            'movie', 'jcvideoplayer/jcplayer',
            'salign','TL'
        ); //end AC code
        document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = playerHTML;
    }
}
```